# replace all nulls with empty strings in a JSONArray

Tags: java, android

Hi i have a JSONObject that i have converted to a JSON Array and i'm wanting to know how to loop through the whole array find any instances of null and replace it with ""?

heres what i have so far but not sure where to go from here

```
JSONObject fullNetworkfile = fullNetworkDataFromFile;
     JSONArray fullNetworkArray = new JSONArray();
     fullNetworkArray.put(fullNetworkfile);
```

Comment: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < fullNetworkArray.length(); i++) {
    Object network = fullNetworkArray.get(i);
    if (network == null) {
        fullNetworkArray.put(i, "");
    }
}
```